# How to insert each array value with 'for'?

Tags: ios, swift

I have one TableView and I have `MyTableViewCell.swift` file. The TableView Cell has two labels. My data array looks like this:

```swift
var fruitArray = [["apple", "red"], ["banana", "yellow"], ["orange", "orange"]]
```

I want to put the fruits and colors on each of the two labels. So I tried like this:

```swift
var fruitArray = [["apple", "red"], ["banana", "yellow"], ["orange", "orange"]]

...
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    fruitArray.count
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        
    for i in fruitArray {
        cell.lblFruit.text = fruitArray[i]
        cell.lblColor.text = fruitArray[i]
    }
    return cell
}
```

But this doesn't work.

```swift
cell.lblFruit.text = fruitArray[i] // not work
cell.lblColor.text = fruitArray[i] // not work
```

How to insert each array value with "for"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the way a table view data source works. A `for` loop is wrong.

Actually `cellForRowAt` works like a `for` loop. It is called once for each row. You have to get the item of the array for the given index path

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    
    let item = fruitArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblFruit.text = item[0]
    cell.lblColor.text = item[1]
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my question is a small example and actually I want to bring a lot of the values in the array. So I thought I should use for.

Comment: As I said a `for` loop is wrong. `cellForRowAt` is called `fruitArray.count` times. You have to get the item at current `indexPath`.

Comment: oh, I understand! Thank you!